# Formula probability of two random variables with density function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am reading through a proof in Brzezniak's *Basic Stochastic Processes* on the Poisson distribution.

If $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent random variables and $f_{\eta}$ is the density of $\eta$ then

$$ P(\{\xi > t-\eta\}\cap\{0\leq \eta \leq t\}) = \int_0^t P(\{\xi > t - s\})f_\eta(s)ds $$

I am stuck because $\{\xi > t-\eta\}$ and $\{0\leq \eta \leq t\}$ are not independent events and I have no idea other than a feeling as to why the probability is on the inside of the integral. Would a proof of the above require starting with the Lebesgue integral $P(A) = \int_A f_\eta dP$ and making a substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(\{\xi > t - \eta\} \cap \{0 \le \eta \le t\})
= E[1_{\xi > t - \eta} 1_{0 \le \eta \le t}]
= E[E[1_{\xi > t - \eta} 1_{0 \le \eta \le t} \mid \eta ]]
= E[ 1_{0 \le \eta \le t} E[1_{\xi > t - \eta} \mid \eta ]].$$
The inner expectation can be viewed as $g(\eta)$ where $g(s) := E[1_{\xi > t-s}] = P(\xi > t-s)$.

---

Alternatively, fleshing out Kavi Rama Murthy's answer:

\begin{align}
P(\{\xi > t - \eta\} \cap \{0 \le \eta \le t\})
&= \iint 1_{x > t - s}(x,s) 1_{0 \le s \le t}(s) \, d(P_\xi(x) \times P_\eta(t))
\\
&= \int \int 1_{x > t - s}(x,s) 1_{0 \le s \le t}(s) \, dP_\xi(x) \, dP_\eta(s)
\\
&= \int 1_{0 \le s \le t}(s) \int 1_{x > t - s}(x,s)  \, dP_\xi(x) \, dP_\eta(s)
\\
&= \int 1_{0 \le s \le t}(s) P(\xi > t-s) \, dP_\eta(s)
\\
&= \int 1_{0 \le s \le t}(s) P(\xi > t-s) f_\eta(s) \, ds.
\end{align}

Comment: Why is the indicator function independent of $\eta$. Well I assume that is why the first expected value is equal to the second expected value. The last equality holds because 1_{$ 0 \leq \eta \leq t$} is $\eta$ measurable correct?

Comment: @AndrewShedlock For the second equality, I am using the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), or the [measure-theoretic definition of conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition). For the last equality, you are correct.

Comment: Oh so that holds for arbitrary random variables instead of just independent random variables?

Comment: @AndrewShedlock Yes. Although upon retrospect I would follow the other answer's suggestion, as the notion of conditional expectation is not really needed here.

Answer (score 1):

LHS is the integral of $I_A$ w.r.t. the product measure $P_\xi \times P_\eta$ where $A=\{(x,y): x>t-y, 0\leq y \leq t\}$. You get the desired equality by applying Fubini/Tonelli's Theorem, integrating w.r.t. $P_\eta$  first and then w.r.t. $P_\xi$.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see how Tonelli's theorem will give us the desired relationship with the density function. Would you mind explaining the calculation?